# How can I access a functional component's getHandlerId() to test react-dnd with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-dnd

I am following the instructions in the [React-DnD project's Testing page](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/testing) to be able to write unit tests with Enzyme, but I can't get the component to get the handler id in order to call `backend.simulateBeginDrag(...)`

I have a simple project setup here: https://github.com/agonzalezjr/react-dnd-enzyme. Basically started with Create-React-App + Typescript, added React-DnD, dustbin/boxes example from ReactDnD, and Enzyme. It runs OK, and the tests run OK too.

This is the test code:

```
  it('drags - with enzyme', () => {
    const BoxWithTestContext = wrapInTestContext(Box)
    const ref = React.createRef()
    
    const root = mount(
      <>
        <BoxWithTestContext ref={ref} name="test" />
      </>
    )
    expect(root).toBeDefined()

    const backend = (ref.current as any).getManager().getBackend()
    expect(backend).toBeDefined()

    // How do I get the component or component's getHandlerId() to be able to call
    // backend.simulateBeginDrag(...), etc...
  });
```

I can see the backend is setup, and there is something registered with an id of "S1", but I need to be able to get that programmatically somehow.

Comment: What is your expected result and what is your actual result?

Comment: I expect to be able to get some object that I can call function `getHandlerId()` on. However, I can't find anything in `root` that exposes that interface.

Comment: FWIW: I ended up using the workaround mentioned here https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/2774#issuecomment-751732540